# how to delete documents which are having highest value in mongodb mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection as mentioned below:

```
{"_id": 1, "movie": "Okkadu", "released": 2003},
{"_id": 2, "movie": "Athadu", "released": 2005},
{"_id": 3, "movie": "Pokiri", "released": 2006},
{"_id": 4, "movie": "Srimanthudu", "released": 2015}
```

I would like to find latest released movies and keep those records and old released movies should be deleted based on released column. In this case only 4th record should remain in collection.

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: hello, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

First you can just do like this

```
db.yourcollection.findOne({}).sort({released: 1}).toArray();
```

You will get latest released date. After this you can just do

```
db.yourcollection.remove({released: {$lt: yourYearFromPrevQuery}});
```

Docs to read.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

Hope this helps